# Error syncing Parity Wallet

Tags: parity

I am trying to sync the Parity wallet to the Ethereum network. I keep getting this error:

```
    Encountered error during state restoration: IO error: /Users/pro/Library/Application 
Support/io.parity.ethereum/chains/ethereum/db/906a34e69aec8c0d/snapshot/restoration/db/000339.log: 
No such file or directory
```

I will appreciate any guidance on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's probably a corrupted database. Please reset your database with:

```
parity db kill
```

This will force you to start your synchronization again but it should only take a few minutes with warp sync.

If this issue perists, your disk might be corrupted and you should run full filesystem checks on it and consider repairing/replacing it.